# Designing "and", "or" Icons

Tags: icon, interface-design

I am trying to come up with a good design for a pair of icons that will be placed above a list of tags which filter a list of items.

Basically the tags that are ticked can search using "and" or using "or" so you can find all items that have "tagA OR tagB" or you can search for all items with "tagA AND tagB".

```
              [] []        <------ Icons
|---------|  |----------|
|Items:   |  |Tags:     |
| - Item1 |  | [] TagA  |
| - Item2 |  | [] TagB  |
| - Item3 |  | [] TagC  |
| - Item4 |  |----------|
| - Item5 |
|---------|
```

I have a few ideas of how to represent this but nothing that I am happy with.

I have a 16x16 area to fit each icon into.

So if anyone has any ideas on a pair icons that would work to convey this idea then I'd be very happy to hear them.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't literally use AND and OR in little boxes?

Comment: There is currently a few of other icons in the same bar and they all use visual icons, so for consistency, but also it would be putting words inside a 16x16 button (which is part of a larger application that I don't have control over), it basically just looks weird on a square button and using a different scale font to everything else in.

Answer (score 2):

For "and" you could obviously use `&` or `+` -- these would be the most intuitive.

For "or" something which indicates a "split" might work.... 
[image]
Just need to be careful it doesn't look like "less than"

Answer (score 2):

> There is a symbol for it in [predicate logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_logic).
>
> "And/or" is just called "or" and is represented as ∨, from the Latin vel meaning or. But note that it's a separate symbol from the letter "v", though similar.
>
> In contrast, ["or"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) in the sense of "this one or that one but never both" is called ["exclusive or"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor) or "xor" and can be symbolized as ⊻ or ⊕.
>
> Also, in programming you might see "and/or" represented as | or as ||, and "xor" represented as ^. Which confusingly looks a lot like ∧, used in logic to mean "and".

I take "ZERO" credit for research or this explanation [Henrik N](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6556/henrik-n) --> [Source - english.stackexchange.com/](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72369/is-there-a-symbol-for-and-or)

I know this is about 'and/or' but the symbols expressed above are used for 'or' in mathematics and programing. Although no overly helpful; BUT hopefully this will give you or someone else some ideas.

Comment: I thought this too, but depending on audience they may not be familiar with these symbols.

Comment: Totally agree, that was my concern also.